# Comparing Directory Structures recursively in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to recursively compare two directories in bash using something I can put into an `if ![ x=y ]` type test.

The directories are intended to have a synchronisation between them using rsync which I'm trying to start with folder actions: file added to directory.

I'm trying to find a test that would let me check recursively if the source and destination directories are basically the same: file names, locations relative to the source/destination head directory and size in MB should be enough. Modification date may throw things off a little due to the way the applications handle the contents of those directories.
A couple of files may have streams being written to them at times. I'd like to start the rsync process on these whenever there is a significant difference in file size, eg. >1MB.

So far the answer at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files) seems to come the closest, but due to differences between MacOS and linux this (and several other) solutions fail. In this case even with gfind installed, "%p" is not accepted as a valid argument (invalid format character).

Other options I've investigated or read about are rsync dry run, and diff. rsync takes a very long time even with --size-only, and I believe diff would take even longer: the drives are networked to each other, and used for media storage.

Is there a way I can get a listing of directory contents and ballpark file sizes as an input for an if statement in a bash script? Or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use the SU code and leave the `printf` part away?

Comment: Anyway, the question as written is rather broad. The example you mention from SU does a purely structure/name based, yet in your question you also mention file sizes, modification dates etc. Also I'm not so sure about your use case here. If you want to rsync anyway, why not just use rsync only which does the diff automatically?

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the reply. I'm not overly familiar with a lot of what I'm reading, and I've been over a lot of sources so I may not be recalling / understanding them all properly. If I understand correctly the SU example does not compare file sizes? This is somewhat important as files may be written to in stream. I tried a rsync dry run --size-only comparison and the check took over half an hour to complete. I'd like to be able to process the comparison a little sooner if possible; for certain operations the entire transfer may take only 1/2 an hour.

Comment: The example on SU only compares file names.

Comment: But what's not really clear yet is: What to you expect to gain from running the comparison first? Basically the real rsync will run the same comparision so at the end you just run it twice.

Comment: So which specific real-world problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: @nohillside Yeah the SU example isn't comparing file sizes, which having streamed files won't accurately represent the difference in directory contents. I don't want to run a rsync comparison twice; I want to check if the contents of one directory are more or less equivalent to another superficially, ie. filename and size. The real world application is a media recording device with rsync daemon connected over a relatively low bandwidth link to a media playing client. Transfer is mpeg2 encoded media and associated metadata files.

Comment: @nohillsideThe aim of the check in this question is to establish if rsync shall be initiated and avoid it if there are no superficial differences between the source and destination locations.

Comment: "The aim of the check in this question is to establish if rsync shall be initiated and avoid it if there are no superficial differences between the source and destination locations" -> This is exactly what rsync does before it starts copying, that's why I'm not sure a separate script helps at the end. I see the point with the file size difference though. Hmm, might be scriptable.

Comment: @nohillside for some reason the rsync check takes a significant amount of time even using dry-run, size-only checking. The time taken to get a ls -l or a /find of both source and destination is trivial in comparison. I'm not sure why rsync takes so much longer in this case but if it's possible to decease time taken for rsync to run a comparison I'm more than happy to follow that approach :)

Comment: Does the output of `du -a DIRECTORY` help?